# Angular-Summernote on-image-upload editor Object Undefined

Tags: angularjs, image-upload, summernote

I'm struggling on figuring out how to use angular-summernote callback on-image-upload.

The code in my view:

```
<summernote data-editable="editable" data-on-image-upload="imageUpload(files, editor)"></summernote>
```

And the imageUplaod function:

```
$scope.imageUpload = function(files, editor) {
    console.log(files);  // FileList
    console.log(editor);  // undefined
    console.log($scope.editable); // undefined
};
```

And the image is not inserted into the editor.
I have tried googling for the implementation example on the imageUpload, but find null. Can anyone show me how to do it?

Answer (score 2):

I struggled with this too. The current documentation for this basic feature is really poor. Anyway, this is how I do it:

```
$scope.imageUpload = function(files) {
    uploadEditorImage(files);
};

function uploadEditorImage(files) {
    if (files != null) {

        // Begin uploading the image.
        // Here I'm using the ngFileUpload module (named 'Upload') to upload files, but you can use $.ajax if you want
        // Remember to include the dependency in your Controller!
        Upload.upload({
            url: 'api/resources/upload-file',
            file: files[0]
        }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {

            // The image has been uploaded to your server.
            // Now we need to insert the image back into the text editor.
            var editor = $.summernote.eventHandler.getModule(),
                uploaded_file_name = data.file_name, // this is the filename as stored on your server.
                file_location = '/uploads/'+uploaded_file_name;

            editor.insertImage($scope.editable, file_location, uplaoded_file_name);

        });

    }

};
```

The important part, to get the image to display back in the editor, is this bit here:

```
var editor = $.summernote.eventHandler.getModule(),
             uploaded_file_name = data.file_name,
             file_location = '/path-where-you-upload-your-image/'+uploaded_file_name;

editor.insertImage($scope.editable, file_location, uploaded_file_name);
```

`$.summernote.eventHandler.getModule()` retrieves all the [API methods](http://summernote.org/#/deep-dive#api) native to summernote. In this case, you need to use the `insertImage()` method in order to insert the uploaded image back into the editor.

If anyone has any cleaner solutions then please go ahead!

Answer (score 1):

instead of using 'editor' object use the following when image uploaded

$('.summernote').summernote('editor.insertImage', url);

Comment: But I don't think that is the angular ways. @M-Sha

Answer (score 1):

I got it through AngularJS + JQuery in this way:

```
$scope.summernoteOptions = {
    height: 300,
    focus: true,
    lang: 'es-ES',
    callbacks: {
        onImageUpload: function(files) {
            var data = new FormData();
            data.append("file", files[0]);
            $.ajax({
                data: data,
                type: "POST",
                url: "/admin/api/insertar-imagen-summernote.php",
                cache: false,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                success: function(url) {
                    $('.summernote').summernote('editor.insertImage', url);
                }
            });
        }
    }
};
```